# Maya to Blender

Tags: import, collada, .fbx

I am currently looking for a way to export from Maya 2017 to Blender.

In most instances, Collada (.DAE) and FBX have proved reliable for what I'm doing, but with these files it appears to be different

Currently, Exporting with Collada (.DAE) results in missing bones, but only when I import into Blender. Re-importing into Maya shows that the bones are indeed still there, so I'm assuming it's something with Blender's Importer.

Exporting with .FBX results in the following error:

"Unsupported FBX Version (7500), Binary Format is Uncompatible!"

I'd like to know if there is any other way to Completely transfer data between the two programs (or if there is a fix to either of the two issues listed above)

Comment: Try exporting an earlier version of FBX, you can select the FBX version when exporting.

Comment: I have no experience with this but did understand Alembic was the answer for this. https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.78/Alembic